# More efficient way to use document.getElementById for checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, checkbox

This section of code uses jQuery to hide/show form fields. When they are hidden the values of those fields are set to empty. This is easy for an input field with its unique ID. I run into trouble with checkboxes. The code below works for three checkboxes. But I have to use this same technique for a set of 26 checkboxes. How can I do this more efficiently?

```
$(".transfer").click(function(){
    if ($('input[name=transfer_position]:checked').val() == "yes" ) {
        //Slide Down Effect
        $(".transfer_details").slideDown("slow");
        document.getElementById('transfer_interest').focus();
    } else {
         //Slide Up Effect
        $(".transfer_details").slideUp("slow");
        document.getElementById('transfer_interest').value = "";
        document.getElementById('select_positions_0').checked = false;
        document.getElementById('select_positions_1').checked = false;
        document.getElementById('select_positions_2').checked = false;
    }
 });
```

---

```
  <li>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="transfer_position" class="transfer" value="yes" id="transfer_position_0" />
        Yes</label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="transfer_position" class="transfer" value="no" id="transfer_position_1" />
        No</label>
  </li>
  <li class="transfer_details">
    <label for="transfer_interest">Why are you interested in transferring to your selected SL positions and what would you bring to that position(s) and team(s)?</label>
    <textarea name="transfer_interest" id="transfer_interest" cols="80" rows="6"> </textarea>
  </li>
  <li class="transfer_details">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="select_positions[]" class="select_positons" value="Resident Advisor" id="select_positions_0" />
        Resident Advisor</label>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="select_positions[]" class="select_positons" value="Programming Assistant" id="select_positions_1" />
        Programming Assistant</label>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="select_positions[]" class="select_positons" value="Social Justice Advocate " id="select_positions_2" />
        Social Justice Advocate </label>
  </li>
```

Comment: They all have the same class. have you considered selecting them by class? or by name? or by common parent?

Answer (score 3):

Use classes, since many elements can share a class.  So you simply uncheck all checkboxes with a certain class:

```
$('.select_positions').attr('checked', false);
```

Comment: Adding a note to be sure user has jQuery library included.

Comment: @KyleB. Given the question was tagged with jQuery and uses jQuery style code, I assumed that was obvious :)

Comment: Apparently I need my glasses, because I missed that.  Good point.

Answer (score 0):

Use the amazing power of jquery's selectors, of course!

```
$('li.transfer_details input[type=checkbox]').prop("checked", false);
```

descendant selector - http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/

setting the checked attribute -
http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use the child selector in conjunction with the checkbox selector, and iterating using the each function in jQuery to accomplish what you're looking for.

Keep in mind this is untested, so its probably going to raise errors and I trust you to fix that.
Beneath your slide up effect, you'd want something like the following:

```
$('.transfer_details > input:checkbox').each(function() {
(this).checked = false;
});
```

Hope this helps and happy coding!